# Как сделать чтобы в header фон с левой стороны выходил за container bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

вот картинка вопроса
https://toster.ru/q/607853

И как лучше сделать, чтобы фон заголовка "СПЕЦТЕХНИКИ" справа доходил до конца сайта?
Тут я понял можно сделать linegradient

Comment: код покажите рабочий

Comment: <header>
  <div class="top-line">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </header>

Comment: header
 min-height: 1000px
 background-image: url(../img/bg-header.jpg)
 background-repeat: no-repeat
 background-size: cover
 background-position: top left

Comment: сейчас фон растянут на всю ширину, а нужно чтобы картинка не залезала на правый отступ container

Comment: чтобы вставить код в меню есть пункт "фрагмент кода". Можно отредактировать сообщение и вставить все что нужно. Ну и если есть живой рабочий сайт - будет проще кинуть ссылку. Иначе на данный момент информации недостаточно.

Comment: http://2kovsha.prospekt.pro/

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать отрицательный `margin`

```css
.with-offset {
  margin-right: -50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-info">
    <h1 class="text-white">MainContent</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="bg-danger">
          <h2>Заголовок 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-warning with-offset">
          <h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я нашел решение по заголовку, через linear-gradient

Comment: А вот как решить вопрос с картинкой фона?

Comment: http://2kovsha.prospekt.pro/
Чтобы картинка доходила до границы правого container
можно сделать background-size: 85%, но много времени уйдет правки в медиа запросах

Comment: http://2kovsha.prospekt.pro/

Answer (score 1):

> фон заголовка "СПЕЦТЕХНИКИ" справа доходил до конца сайта

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.header-content .h1-span {
  position: relative;
}

.header-content .h1-span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(250, 190, 13, 0.7);
  right: -3000px;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  max-width:70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .wrap-container {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.container:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top: -90px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:-1000px;
    background: url("http://placeimg.com/500/300/an") no-repeat 100% 0/100% 100%;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-container">
      <div class="header-content">
      <h1>Аренда<div class="h1-span"><span>спецтехники</span></div></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

для фона что-то в этом роде через псевдоэлемент :after,

```
 .container {
position:relative;
} 
    .container:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top: -90px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:-2000px;
    background: url(../img/bg-header.jpg) no-repeat 100% 0/auto 100%;
    }
```

Comment: это я понял, а на счет фона что?

Comment: Как его грамотно сдвинуть влево адаптивно?

Comment: background-size: contain ну или можно background-size:cover  или background-size: 100% auto - в зависимости от нужного внешнего вида

Comment: Пробую по всякому, но что-то не встает на месть
вот сетка bootstrap в макете
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p37NXgdKJH8gSMZCJGmqsbO8-mniY_AK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ну если так, чтобы справа было белое, тогда с псевдоэлементами шаманить, добавила в ответ выше, что-то в этом роде.